# ANDROID_HOME environment variable not set error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I have already set my ANDROID_HOME directory to sdk path .
echo $ANDROID_HOME=/Users/xyz/Library/Android/sdk

i still get this error by appium server.Using testNG framework..Running my first app

Comment: Are you using mac or windows?

Comment: i am getting this error on all samples i am running :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to export tools and platform-tools to access adb command.
If you using mac open then terminal and If you are in windows open .bash_profile 
and execute as follows

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$(whoami)/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it can't find `adb` from your defined paths. Check if you've added the android `platform-tools` folder to the $PATH variable. It's the one that contains `adb`

In your `.bash_profile`, try adding this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

In the above line, I added both the `tools` and `platform-tools` folder in the `PATH` variable.